# $_POST and variable in the string - not sure why it is not working

Tags: php, mysql, post, php-5.6

I have this non-dynamic script works like this:

```
<p>Environment: <select name="formEnvironment" value="" >
<option value="TEST" <?= $_POST['formEnvironment'] == TEST ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Test</option>
<option value="PROD" <?= $_POST['formEnvironment'] == PROD ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Production</option>
</select></p>
```

---

As I have tried to make it more dynamic as possible within variables.  I have problems with code within while nest and I do think it has to do with strings and variables mixing together which makes it more complicated. Any assistance with what is right way to code in that regard.  I would appreciate assistance as I am only few months into PHP.

```
function DropDownItems($itemName, $query, $connection)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $MAS = "$_POST['form"{$itemName}"']";
        echo "<option value=\"{$row['DDVALUE']}\" ";
        echo "<?= "{$MAS}" == "{$row['DDVALUE']}" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>"{$row['DDTEXT']}"</option>";

    }
}

$itemName="Environment";
$query = "SELECT DDVALUE, DDTEXT FROM DDLISTS WHERE FIELDNAME='".$itemName."' ORDER BY DDTEXT ASC";
echo "<p>$itemName.": <select name='form".$itemName."'>";
echo "<option value=''>Select below:</option>";
DropDownItems($itemName, $query, $connection);
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: `<?=` is the short php syntax for echo, your already "inside" php so should not be using it as you are. I see other basic syntax errors in the code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its never a good idea to echo in functions, instead just return an array and then loop over it.

You can also break out of PHP so you don't need to do lots of echos.

So many syntax errors, so I've just rewrote it:

```
<?php
function DropDownItems($itemName, $query, $connection) {
    $return = [];
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $return[] = [
            'value' => $row['DDVALUE'],
            'label' => $row['DDTEXT']
        ];
    }
    return $return;
}

$itemName="Environment";
$query = "SELECT DDVALUE, DDTEXT FROM DDLISTS WHERE FIELDNAME='".$itemName."' ORDER BY DDTEXT ASC";
?>
<p><?= $itemName ?>
    <select name="form<?= $itemName ?>">
        <option value="">Select below:</option>
        <?php foreach (DropDownItems($itemName, $query, $connection) as $item): ?>
        <option value="<?= $item['value'] ?>"<?= (isset($_POST['form'.$itemName]) && $_POST['form'.$itemName] === $item['value'] ? ' selected' : '') ?>><?= $item['label'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
</p>
```

Be aware of SQL injections, if `$itemName="Environment";` is user supplied you should change the code to use [prepared queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the syntax errors. And made the code a little more readable. You can try the below code. Haven't tested it, hope it works fine.

```
<?php
    function DropDownItems($itemName, $query, $connection)
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $html = '';

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $MAS = $_POST['form'.$itemName];
            $html .= "<option value=\"{$row['DDVALUE']}\" ";
            $html .= ( $MAS == $row['DDVALUE'] ? 'selected' : '' ).">{$row['DDTEXT']}</option>";
        }

        return $html;
    }

    $itemName="Environment";
    $query = "SELECT DDVALUE, DDTEXT FROM DDLISTS WHERE FIELDNAME='".$itemName."' ORDER BY DDTEXT ASC";
    echo "<p>$itemName".": <select name='form".$itemName."'>";
    echo "<option value=''>Select below:</option>";
    echo DropDownItems($itemName, $query, $connection);
    echo "</select>";
?>
```